# I produce a list of the top 3 most popular movies for a given genre for the current month

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my assignment about DVD rental. The question is to find top(3) famous rented movie for given genre.

Below is my half done weird code.

```
SELECT TOP(3)
FROM MOVIE mv
INNER JOIN DVD dvd ON dvd.movie_id = mv.movie_id
INNER JOIN RENTAL rt ON rt.dvd_id = dvd.dvd_id
WHERE movie_id = movie_id
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: Please don't provide links to off site file shares. If you have information that is important to the question, include it in the question. The majority of people using Stack overflow are either IT professions or experienced enthusiasts and know far better than to download a file from an anonymous person on the internet.

Comment: uh okay... because i dk how to add the pic into the ques. and thanks for your prompt.:)

Answer (score 0):

You have a good start. If you want to get the most rented movies, you want to query the movie, and then count the amount of times it was rented. Then you select the top 3 results, order it in descending order, and include a WITH TIES hint to make sure you include results that have the same count as most rented.

```
SELECT TOP 3 WITH TIES mv.movie, COUNT(rt.id) AS times_rented
FROM MOVIE mv
INNER JOIN DVD dvd ON dvd.movie_id = mv.movie_id
INNER JOIN RENTAL rt ON rt.dvd_id = dvd.dvd_id
GROUP BY mv.movie
ORDER BY COUNT(rt.id) DESC
```

Comment: aww, no wonder i dont know how to do , i dont know the WITH TIES hints,thanks for helping and teaching me.

Answer (score 0):

This query will return all movie info for the top N (with ties) movies by genre rented in a given time period.

```
declare @StartDate date = '20190601'
    ,@EndDate date = '20190630'
    ,@Top int = 3

;With RentalCounts as
(
SELECT genre, mv.movie_id, Count(*) Ct
FROM MOVIE mv
INNER JOIN DVD dvd ON dvd.movie_id = mv.movie_id
INNER JOIN RENTAL rt ON rt.dvd_id = dvd.dvd_id
WHERE rt.[RentalDate] between @StartDate and @EndDate
group by genre, mv.movie_id
)
, ranked as
(
select *, ranked = rank() over (partition by movie_id, genre order by Ct desc)
from RentalCounts 
)

select mv.*
from ranked r
   join movie m on movie.movie_id = r.MovieID
where ranked.Ct <=@top
```